# How to create a copy of an existing DataFrame(panda)?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, clone

I have just started exploring pandas. I tried applying logarithmic scaling to a Dataframe column without affecting the source Dataframe. I passed the existing DataFrame(data_source) to the DataFrame constructor thinking that it would create a copy.

```
data_source = pd.read_csv("abc.csv")
log_data = pd.DataFrame(data = data_source).apply(lambda x: np.log(x + 1))
```

I think it works properly but is it a recommended/correct way of applying scaling on a copied DataFrame ? How is it different from the 'DataFrame.copy' function?

Comment: `apply` already makes a new dataframe (and you could just do `np.log(data_source+1)` anyway, or `np.log1p(data_source)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame(data = data_source)` does not make a copy. This is [documented](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) in the docs for the `copy` argument to the constructor:

> **copy** : *boolean, default False*
>   Copy data from inputs. Only affects DataFrame / 2d ndarray input

This is also easily observed by trying to mutate the result:

```
>>> x = pandas.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [1., 2., 3.]})
>>> y = pandas.DataFrame(x)
>>> x
   x    y
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  3.0
>>> y
   x    y
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  3.0
>>> y.iloc[0, 0] = 2
>>> x
   x    y
0  2  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  3.0
```

If you want a copy, call the `copy` method. You don't need a copy, though. `apply` already returns a new dataframe, and better yet, you can call `numpy.log` or `numpy.log1p` on dataframes directly:

```
>>> x = pandas.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [1., 2., 3.]})
>>> numpy.log1p(x)
          x         y
0  0.693147  0.693147
1  1.098612  1.098612
2  1.386294  1.386294
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In my code, 'apply' method created the copy but I thought it was done by pd.DataFrame(data = data_source).

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.apply`, `.applymap` and `np.log` do not change the original data, so it is not necessary to `copy()`

also, `np.log` accepts arrays, so in this particular case it would be better to write:

```
log_data = pd.DataFrame(np.log(data_source.values + 1), 
                        columns=data_source.columns, 
                        index=data_source.index)
```